# Comparing values with previous data in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm just looking into Apache Spark and I'm not sure if this is possible or is the right tool..

Here my case:

1. I have N sources (think like and industrial plant)
2. Each source generate an entry each minute (so my key should be [source_ID, timestamp+)
3. In each entry I have an hash table from reading the values of some sensors (eg [T1=100, T2=120, ...)

Now what I need to do is the "*last 10 minutes average*" of T1 (for the specific source_ID) and compare with the "*last 10 minutes average*" of 3 days ago (eg. **timestamp_now**=2016-01-26T22:04:00 **timestamp_3daysago**=20160123T22:04:00) and save the difference between the two in a new variable that needs to be saved with the "row"

I repeat I don't know if Spark is the right tool.

At the moment I've implemented this in python + PostgreSQL but the overhead of looking back for each row is killing the database

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us more about the variety of data, the volume of data? Also, are you planning on using HDFS (Hadoop) and Spark or just Spark?

Comment: I really don't know at the moment if is best to use Hadoop or just plain Spark. For sizing I have a list of sensor reading each minute for each source, with about 50 sensors, for at least 350 sources. The data will be received in bulks each hour or so. Thanks!

Comment: As it is a batch job that is feeding the data store, I am not sure whether Spark Streaming would be best for this project. I would say you can use Spark as an analysis engine though as it doesn't have to use the Hadoop platform entirely.

Comment: So you need a store where 1) you can store multiple columns, possible sparse 2) you add a batch regularly 3) you access the data in small (10 minute) slices.  One data store that can help is HBase. You can still use spark through a connector.